# Closing an Outlook Contact window created and opened from code shuts down Outlook itself (bad)?

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook

I have an C# WPF application that reads in a bunch of local Outlook contacts and stores them in memory. When a search is conducted in the app, a list of ResultObjects is generated and bound to a ListBox which is show onscreen in my app. A property of a ResultObject is the Outlook Contact it was derived from (Outlook.ContactItem), and I use that to bind to a buttons Tag property (which can be anything you want to assign to it), so that when a user click on the button beside a result they want, the Outlook contact window itself will open to display the contact.

When I pull the list of contacts initially an instance of Outlook is required and created, and the running process is there.

**public Outlook.Application usersOutlook = new Outlook.Application();**

The problem is, after my code opens an Outlook contact window for the object associated with the clicked button:

**buttonContact = (Outlook.ContactItem) ((Button)sender).Tag;
   buttonContact.Display();**

and then the user closes that window, my running Outlook.Application (and it's process/PID) closes with it - *which is not what I want*. I need Outlook to stay running for the next contact the user wants to see. With no Outlook still running, the button to show the contact fails. If I brute force a new instance of Outlook, thus creating a new process, clicking the button to show a contact raises an nasty "**RPC Server is Unavailable**" error which I've yet been able to get around / figure out.

The only way for my app to work properly is if the user starts up Outlook them selves, so the whole app is running on their machine, and then they leave it running while my app is running. That way when they close a contact opened by Outlook via my code, Outlook itself keeps chugging along, and then next contact the user wants to see will work . That is not an acceptable compramise for my customer - they demand Outlook running not be a requirement for the user. The app needs to create a hidden instance in code-behind and maintain it for the lifetime of my running app.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest keeping the id of Outlook items in the Tag property of your controls instead. So, you will be able to recover them back with any Outlook instance (even if it is gone). The [GetItemFromID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869893(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Namespace class returns a Microsoft Outlook item identified by the specified entry ID (if valid). For more information about Entry IDs, see the [EntryID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863318.aspx) property:

> A MAPI store provider assigns a unique ID string when an item is created in its store. Therefore, the EntryID property is not set for an Outlook item until it is saved or sent. The Entry ID changes when an item is moved into another store, for example, from your Inbox to a Microsoft Exchange Server public folder, or from one Personal Folders (.pst) file to another .pst file. Solutions should not depend on the EntryID property to be unique unless items will not be moved. The EntryID property returns a MAPI long-term Entry ID.

Answer (score 1):

That's what Outlook does - closes itself when the last window (`Explorer` or `Inspector`) is closed, even if there are still references to Outlook Object Model objects. The only exceptions are the `Explorer` and `Inspector` objects, even if they are not visible.

Try to retrieve an `Explorer` object from an instance of the `MAPIFolder` object (`MAPIFolder.GetExplorer`) and keep it referenced until you are done. You don't have to do anything with it, just keep it referenced in a global/class variable. `MAPIFolder` can be any Outlook folder, e.g. the default Contacts folder returned by `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)`.